# Params sent are not the same in a backbone's model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

In a simple backbone's application, I have this model :

```
class Rcbvm2.Models.Item extends Backbone.Model
  initialize: (modelName) ->
    @modelName = modelName
    @paramRoot = @modelName
    @urlRoot = "http://localhost:3000/#{@modelName}"
```

When I try this :

```
item = new Rcbvm2.Models.Item('pages')
item.set('body', 'test')
item.id = 2
item.save()
```

So, there is a request send to my rails application with this :

```
Started PUT "/pages/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-01 19:39:40 -0400
Processing by PagesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"pages"=>{"silent"=>true}, "body"=>"test", "id"=>"2", "page"=>{"body"=>"test"}}
```

Ok, it works. My problem is when I do this :

```
item = new Rcbvm2.Models.Item('news') //change the model's name
item.set('body', 'test')
item.id = 2
item.save()
```

I have this :

```
Started PUT "/news/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-01 19:40:04 -0400
Processing by NewsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"news"=>{"silent"=>true}, "body"=>"test1", "id"=>"2"}
```

As you could see, there is "body" in the hash "new".

**EDIT 1**

With page I have this `"page"=>{"body"=>"test"}` , with news, there is nothing...

**END EDIT 1**

I also tried with the model "users", a model that doesn't exist in my rails application and It's the same think than news.

I don't undestand. Do you have an idea?

**Edit 2**

This is my routes :

```
resources :pages
resources :news
```

Same thing for both.

Comment: What do you mean by "As you could see, there is "body" in the hash "new".? Can you clearly state your problem?

Comment: I edited my question. In the parameters sent, there is no "new" hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. First, "new" seems to be a reserved word. Secondly, I must to add the right attr_accessible in my models.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think everything is right, the problem is you have to return the correct JSON in your News Controller. Look at your Pages Controller, and compare it with your News Controller.

Comment: The new's controller is exactly the same than page's controller